# Regex Signification '[:*]+' and comparison with a LINQ request

Tags: c#, regex, linq, regex-lookarounds

I'm not familiair with Regex.

Could you explain me that rule please ?

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "[:*]+", "");
```

Could it be done easier/faster with a LINQ request or with a simple `str.replace()`?

Comment: Bookmark this: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl

Comment: Neither easier nor faster. You would need multiple replace calls which would create multiple temporary strings. LINQ would be much worse as it would first convert the string to a char array, filter it and rebuild it. In any case, this would work only for trivial cases as anything more complex (eg checking for two or more of the characters) would require complex code

Comment: There's a great book, *Mastering Regular Expressions* by Jeffrey E. F. Friedl (O'Reilly & Associates) that I'd urge you to read. Regular expressions are a very important skill for a programmer to learn to use well.

Comment: this website is really nice, thanks :)

Comment: I already made this kind of line : `str.Replace('x', '').Replace('y', '');` Would it be better to switch on a Regex expression like `str = Regex.Replace(str, "[xy]+", "");` ?

Comment: In this test http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance.aspx the `string.Replace()` is 5 times faster than `Regex.Replace()` method. So it should be still 2 times faster if i'm using `string.Replace().Replace()` in theory. But the code is (imo) dirty with `string.Replace().Replace()`. what do you think about it please ?

Answer (score 3):

The [] defines a group of characters that can fill the spot and the + indicates that it is one or more of them.  This will match any series of : and * characters.  For example *** or :*: or :.  It will take anything that matches that and remove it since it is replacing them with nothing.

As for faster ways to do this.  Especially if you are doing it more than once and/or can compile the regex to be used more than once, this is exactly the kind of thing Regex is designed to handle quickly and efficiently.

Comment: ok thanks. I though the * was a special char in regex, but as you describe this rule, it's probably not a special char inside the [].

Comment: @wyles correct, inside[] it is just a list of characters that make up the character class you are defining.  A pattern makes no sense within a [].